# Python - regex to split a column in 2 in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a column in a dataframe with strings like this "Boris" and other with extra text between paranthesis, like this "Igor (king)".
I just want to get a column with Boris / Igor / ...   (everything between parenthesis deleted).
I tried this

```
pattern = '(^[\w]*)(?:[w]* \()'
Test =df['column'].str.extract(pattern)
```

I got back only the names that have extra text with parenthesis : i get NaN / Igor /Nan

Some help ?

Comment: Please update the question with some sample rows from the DataFrame so we can debug the regex.

Comment: use re.sub with `\([^()]+\)` or use `(^\w+) \([^()]+\)` and replace with group 1 https://regex101.com/r/7cZq00/1

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Boris', 'Igor (King)', "Jack (prince of Persia)"]})
df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r"\(.*\)", "", x).strip())
```

Output:

```
    name
0   Boris
1   Igor
2   Jack
```

Comment: Thanks Mujiga.
I stilll have an issue with stings like these "Jack (prince of Persia)" : nothing is replaced.
I still have "Jack (prince of Persia)"

Comment: May be replace everything inbetween and including `()`. Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the first word and remove the following contents between the parenthesis, you have to extend your pattern to match till the closing parenthesis.

You could use `str.replace` and use capture group 1 in the replacement.

```
^(\w+) \([^()]+\)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(\w+)`  Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word characters followed by a space, or use `\s+` to match 1+ whitespace characters instead
- `\([^()]+\)` Match from `(` till `)` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any character except `(` or `)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kSj5cK/1)

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column': ['Boris', 'Igor (King)', 'Jack (prince of Persia)']})
df =df['column'].str.replace(r"^(\w+) \([^()]+\)", r"\1")
print(df)
```

Output

```
0    Boris
1     Igor
2     Jack
```